# Adding together matrices in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

As part of a program I'm writing, I've written a code segment to add together two matrices. They are both guaranteed to be square, and of the same size, but the matrix dimensions are variable, and I'm not entirely sure in advance exactly what they'll be (although I should be able to ascertain that immediately before executing this, since I'll have the matrices - right?) My code is as follows:

```
double MatrixAdder( double A, double B, int MatrixSize )
{   
    vector <double> C[ MatrixSize ] [ MatrixSize ] ;
    int i, j ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < MatrixSize ; i++ )
    {
            for ( j = 0 ; j < MatrixSize ; j++ )
        {
            C[ i ][ j ] = A[ i ][ j ] + B[ i ][ j ] ;
        } ;
    } ;
} ;
```

I keep coming up with the following error:

invalid types 'double[int]' for array subscript

It flags up on the A[ i ][ j ] and B[ i ][ j ] parts of C[ i ][ j ] = A[ i ][ j ] + B[ i ][ j ].

I've got the impression from other answers I've looked at that I may need to define a new double(int) function to overcome this, but I'm really not sure how to overcome this.

P.S. Sorry if this isn't very clear - this is my first post, and I'll try to provide clarification as requested.

Comment: P.P.S. When I talk about dimension sizes, I mean that I believe I should be able to define variables that tell what those dimension sizes are for the relevant matrices (i.e. at execution time.) I don't know what they'll be at compile time though.

Comment: `double A` is a double, not a matrix struct. And in order to create a bidimensional array with `vector` you should use `vector<vector<double> >`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your input parameter `A` & `B` which are `double`.

If you want to go with vector you should use: `vector<vector<double>>`

```
vector<vector<double>> MatrixAdder(const vector<vector<double>>& A, const vector<vector<double>>& B)
{   
    vector<vector<double>> C (A.size());
    int i, j ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < A.size() ; i++ )
    {
        C[i].resize(A[i].size());
        for ( j = 0 ; j < A[i].size() ; j++ )
        {
            C[ i ][ j ] = A[ i ][ j ] + B[ i ][ j ] ;
        }
    }

    return C;
}
```

Note that with this solution you don't need to pass the array size.

Comment: I think I can work out how this functions (I'm trying to teach myself C++ by applying what I've learned, so what kvoboriev said about existing libraries isn't really what I wanted.) 

I might need to debug the sections of my code that use matrix addition now, but hopefully I'll be able to do that on my own. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have defined matrices A and B elsewhere, but you are telling the function that A and B are not matrices or arrays, just variables of type double. Try to change your function to this:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> Matrix;
Matrix MatrixAdder(Matrix A, Matrix B)
```

Jerome is correct when saying that you don't actually need to provide matrix size in this implementation. If you wanted to deal with arrays instead, then you would need to (would not recommend this). On another note, since you are not going to be changing matrix A or B, I would recommend you pass them in by const reference. That is:

```
Matrix MatrixAdder(const Matrix &A, const Matrix &B)
```

This is just good practice, plus if you are going to ever end up using this for huge matrices, copying the matrices A and B will be a slow process (instead of simply taking reference to them).

Comment: Good point about needing to define sizes for arrays - and I'd completely forgotten about vectors (when I mentioned arrays, turns out what I meant was multi-dimensional double varibles. Oops...)

Anyway, I'll go through the examples given here, see what works well for me, and then I'll come back and accept an answer later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to implement matrix operation you could use something like this

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> DMatrix;

void MatrixAdder( DMatrix const& A, DMatrix const& B, DMatrix& res )
{   
    res.resize(A.size());
    for ( int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++ )
    {
        res[i].resize(A[i].size);
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < A(i).size ; j++ )
            res[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
    } 
}
```

But it more easy and properly to use existing libraries.

Comment: Since I'm trying to improve my understanding of C++ in general, I'd rather avoid libraries if possible. Thank you very much for your assistance though - there's other sections of my code where I'm encountering the same error, and hopefully I'll now be able to fix those without any further help.

Thanks again for taking the time to help me out though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a couple errors here. You say that you function MatrixAdder receives a double A and a double B.
But a simple double doesn't isn't an array of doubles or a double dimension array of doubles...

In order to make it work properly you should do something like passing a double ** A and a double ** B  to it, where it has been previously dynamically allocated.

Also, you don't need to put that many semicolons. After the for(){...} and after the functions definition there isn't necessary to use a semicolon, although it won't give you errors in this case.